# Table View search results not displaying correctly

Tags: swift, uisearchbar

I have just managed to get my search bar implemented into my table view after a lot of issues. The actual search itself to be working from what I can tell, however the results are not being displayed correctly as I haven't managed to add the 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' search code.

This is the tutorial I am following: http://www.appcoda.com/search-bar-tutorial-ios7/

I am having issues trying to translate some lines of code into Swift. For example, I don't have any idea what this line would be in Swift, nor what it is used for:

```
Recipe *recipe = nil;
```

This is my current code:

```
    func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: NSString) {
    let resultPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF contains[cd] %@", searchText)
    searchResults = arrayDataPayments.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(resultPredicate)
}

func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController!, shouldReloadTableForSearchString searchString: String!) -> Bool {
    self.filterContentForSearchText(searchString)
    return true
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    println(arrayObject.paymentsArray().count)

    if tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView {
        return searchResults.count
    } else {
    if arrayObject.paymentsArray().count == 0 {
        if enterButtonTapped == false {
            backgroundLabel.text = "Before you add any transactions, you must first set a budget. You can do this by tapping the 'Budget' tab."
        } else {
            backgroundLabel.text = "You haven't added any transactions yet. Tap the add button to add a new transaction."
        }
        backgroundLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.width, self.view.bounds.height)
        backgroundLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        backgroundLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        backgroundLabel.sizeToFit()
        backgroundLabel.hidden = false
        backgroundLabel.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()

        self.tableView.backgroundView = backgroundLabel
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
        self.tableView.scrollEnabled = false
        return 0
    } else {
        backgroundLabel.hidden = true
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.SingleLine
        self.tableView.scrollEnabled = true
        return arrayObject.paymentsArray().count
    }
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
    var cell:CustomTransactionTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CustomTransactionTableViewCell
    cell.paymentNameLabel.text = (arrayObject.paymentsArray().objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)) as String
    cell.costLabel.text = (arrayObject.costArray().objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)) as String
    cell.dateLabel.text = (arrayObject.dateArray().objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)) as String

    if arrayObject.imageArray().objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as NSObject == 0 {
        cell.paymentArrowImage.hidden = false
        cell.creditArrowImage.hidden = true
    } else if arrayObject.imageArray().objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as NSObject == 1 {
        cell.creditArrowImage.hidden = false
        cell.paymentArrowImage.hidden = true
    }

    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {

        if let tv=tableView {
            var valueToRemove: AnyObject! = arrayDataValue.objectAtIndex(indexPath!.row)
            println(valueToRemove)

            if arrayObject.imageArray().objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as NSObject == 0 {
                totalSpendingsCounter = totalSpendingsCounter - Double(valueToRemove as NSNumber)
            } else if arrayObject.imageArray().objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as NSObject == 1 {
                totalCreditCounter = totalCreditCounter - Double(valueToRemove as NSNumber)
            }

            arrayDataCost.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath!.row)
            arrayDataImage.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath!.row)
            arrayDataPayments.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath!.row)
            arrayDataDate.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath!.row)
            arrayDataValue.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath!.row)
            tv.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            newTransactionEntered = true
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction then I would be very grateful. This is one of the last stages of my first app and it has been the part I have found the most difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same `tableView` to show the search results which is not the best way to go about this.

Create a new `UITableViewController` subclass then you can do something like this:

```
    searchResultsViewController = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SearchResults") as? MySearchResultViewController

    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchResultsViewController)
    searchController!.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
    searchController!.searchResultsUpdater = searchResultsViewController
```

Your `MySearchResultViewController` should conform to the `UISearchResultsUpdating` protocol and implement `updateSearchResultsForSearchController:`. When you start searching, `UIKit`  automatically presents your `searchResultsViewController` and takes care of adding its view to the hierarchy and removes it when necessary.

Also, it's not a good practice to set your `tableView` properties inside a function that its job is to only return `numberOfRowsInSection`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Since this is my first app, I've accepted that some techniques I use in my code may not be ideal. As the method I am currently using seems to work well, and I understand it, I would prefer to stick to that rather than redoing a large part of my table view code. I should mention that it will work as intended once I figure out the 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' code. At the moment, if I have cells 'A', 'B', 'C' and 'AA' and search for 'A' then it displays 'A' and 'B'. If I search for 'C', 'B' or 'AA' then it displays just 'A'. So clearly the search is working, it's just not...